# Why does IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping field always return false? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Since yesterday the API response for `itemlookup` is always returning `false` to the field `IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping`*(which means the product is not prime)* while checking the product on the link shows that the product is prime

Can anyone tell how to find out if the product is prime or not?

Comment: We are having the same issue. Couldn't find any api changes that could explain this. Is it a specific category of products in your case ?

Comment: any product, looks either a bug or api change?

Comment: thread on amazon forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=631081#631081

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in their system. We've been experiencing the same issue since Monday (I think, weren't actually closely monitoring it). Worked fine before, we changed nothing, and now it's returning no results.